# Detect when song stops playing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller

This seems like something really basic but how do I execute a function when a song ends?  I am playing one item at at time, and when it ends (or if possible, 10 seconds before it ends) I would like to call a function that gets the next song from a webservice.

I *think* it's handled in the `MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` notification but am not sure.  For the record, this notification only needs to be when the song ends (not pauses).

All I have is this, which is the function for the above observer:

```
- (void) handle_PlaybackStateChanged: (id) notification
{
    MPMusicPlaybackState playbackState = [musicPlayer playbackState];
}
```

How do I find out if the song has ended?  Also, is it possible create an observer/function when there are 10 seconds left on the song?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you receive the notification you can look up the [playbackState](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMusicPlaybackState) property of the MPMusicPlayerController.

As for executing a function 10 seconds before the song ends, you could set up a timer to execute in the future based on the length of the song minus 10 seconds, you would need to cancel that timer if the user changes the `playbackState` or selects a different song.

Comment: Would `MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped` indicate the song has finished?  That is, if my app has no stop button, this will not be triggered in any other way?